# Why does my String getting deleted in C# OOP?

Tags: c#, json

I am working on a program with a RestAPI. If I run the first function "ValidateLogin" the access_token will be safed in my User object, when I run the second function "ValidateAuth" on a other window (wpf) then the access token will get deleted.

Here is my RestAPI class to work with:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Serialization.Json;
using software.Objects;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace software.Operation
{
    class RestAPI
    {
        private User usr = new User();

        public string loginapikey = "XXXX";


        public String ValidateLogin(String username, String password)
        {

            var client = new RestClient("https://XXXXXX.de/user/login");
            client.UseJson();
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", loginapikey);
            request.AddJsonBody(new { user = username, password = password });

            if (username == "")
            {
                cmd.sendVMS("No username given");
                return "no_usr_input_given";
            }
            else if (password == "")
            {
                cmd.sendVMS("No password given");
                return "no_pass_given";
            }
            else
            {
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                if (response.Content.Contains("User logged in sucessfully"))
                {
                    cmd.sendVMS(response.Content);

                    dynamic api = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                    var token = api.data;

                    usr.access_token = token.ToString();
                    cmd.sendVMS(usr.access_token);

                    LoginTwoFactor twoFactor = new LoginTwoFactor();
                    twoFactor.ShowDialog();
                }
                else if (response.Content.Contains("Account is not valid"))
                {
                    return "usr_acc_wrong";
                    cmd.sendVMS("Login fail caused by: " + response.Content);
                }
                else if (response.Content.Contains("Account does not exists"))
                {
                    return "usr_not_exists";
                    cmd.sendVMS("Login fail caused by: " + response.Content);
                }
                else
                {
                    return "api_error";
                    cmd.sendVMS("There's a problem with the RestAPI: " + response.Content);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String validateAuth(String authcode_input)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://XXXXXX.de/user/2fa/validate");
            client.UseJson();
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", loginapikey);
            request.AddJsonBody(new { token = usr.access_token, authcode = authcode_input });

            if (authcode_input == "")
            {
                return "no_authcode_given";
            } else
            {
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                //dynamic api = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                //var data = api.data;
                cmd.sendVMS(usr.access_token);
                cmd.sendVMS(response.Content);
                //String valid = jObject.GetValue("data").Value<bool>();

                //if(valid == )
                //{
                //    return "is_valid";
                //} else
                //{
                //    return "is_not_valid";
                //}
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my User class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace software.Objects
{
    class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int forumdid { get; set; }
        public int staffrank { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does anyone of you know the problem?

Sincerely,
Paul

Comment: I am very confused. What does this have to do with OOP? What do you mean by deleted (from a persistent store?)? What does this have to do with WPF?

Comment: i think you're initializing the RestAPI Class in every WPF Window, correct ?

Comment: I set the access_token in the ValidateLogin function and when the login was valid, then a new window opens. When you type in the two factor code then the validateAuth function starts, this only works with the access_token and currently when I call the function access_token is null.

Comment: @pbachman No, I only use intialize the class in the RestAPI class, but I have to intialize the RestAPI in diffrent classes (is that the problem?).

Comment: @P.Artjomow yes, this is the reason why access_token is null in the other window class.

Comment: @pbachman Okay thanks, do you know to fix it? I'm currently using `private RestAPI api = new RestAPI()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that some more code is missing, but if it is truly a Rest API then each web request will (normally) get a new instance of the controller and therefor, your User object will be re-initialized with a `new User()`.

How and where do you instantiate the RestAPI object?

EDIT:

As you confirmed that your initializing a new RestAPI in every window, that explains why your User object will be empty every time.

The most simple solution would be to mark the usr field as `static` and only initialize it in the ValidateLogin method. The static field will remain the same between instances of the RestAPI class.

This isn't really a good practice though as it would mean that another user logging in would override the previous one. It will work for your particular use case, but normally it would be the backend's responsibility to hold this kind of data, in a cache, and/or database, of some sorts.

Comment: Currently I am using the RestAPI object in two diffrent login windows with the following code: `private RestAPI api = new RestAPI();`

Comment: @P.Artjomow that's your problem. The class is getting initialized in both windows. It is _not_ the same object and will thus not contain the same state.

Comment: Is there any simple solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the access_token in the User Class and every time you initialize the RestAPI Class, the User Class will be also initialized (and the access_token will be null).

The RestAPI class doesn't need to be initialized in every WPF Window Class. Use a MVVM pattern, to be able to share the access_token between the WPF Windows. I would recommend the MVVM Light framework [http://www.mvvmlight.net/](http://www.mvvmlight.net)